Why is Rabbitmq server crashing with 'Cannot get connection id for node' error?
I installed Erlang 25 and then Rabbitmq 3.10.6. This is Windows Server 2022. When I start RabbitMQ service, it starts but then crash. The only entry in the log is:
2024-11-21 15:37:34.801000-05:00 [notice] <0.219.0> Logging: configured log handlers are now ACTIVE
2024-11-21 15:37:36.645000-05:00 [error] <0.60.0> 
2024-11-21 15:37:36.645000-05:00 [error] <0.60.0> ** Cannot get connection id for node rabbit@Server
2024-11-21 15:37:36.645000-05:00 [error] <0.60.0> 

The hostname is Server. I created a RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@Server in the conf file. Did not make a difference. This is attached to the domain. Logged in as Admin.

Did you checked the firewall settings...

the rabbitmq version that you refer is no longer supported , best would be to pick a supported configuration from the RabbitMQ supported compatibility table here https://www.rabbitmq.com/docs/which-erlang
